# how to prevent bootsrap modal from scrolling up when closed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal

is it possible to stop the page from scrolling up when a modal is closed?

I already tried doing this:

```
<a onclick="$('.modal').modal('toggle');">Close</a>
<a onclick="$('.modal').modal('hide');">Close</a>
```

Comment: you like to disable scrolling on whole page when modal is close ?

Comment: @bobi No, when the modal is closed it will auto scroll to the top of the page. that's what I'm trying to stop from happening.

Comment: show the whole code becase BS modal is not doing it by default